# How can i execute multiple queries using prepared statments?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute 2 queries at the same time. I know I can do this using `mysqli::multi_query`.

But is there any way I can perform a multiple queries using prepared statements?

Below is an example of my query Thanks!

```
$delete_all_options = "DELETE FROM option_categories WHERE item_id = ?; ";
$delete_all_options .= "DELETE FROM option_names WHERE option_category_id = ?";
$delete_stmt = $db->prepare($delete_all_options);
//Execute statement ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use transactions. Here's an explanation for using transactions with PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php . Transactions can be used also with the MySQLi extension, by setting `MySQLi::autocommit(false)` and then committing with `MySQLi::commit()` (with PHP 5.5+ you can also use `MySQLi::begin_transaction()` and other methods).

Transactions execute multiple queries "at once" and if one query fails all the transaction is reverted.

Comment: ohh okay. I gotchya. I will definitely look into that. Thanks a lot for your help.